# Is there a simple way to upload Image with preview using IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, upload

I am looking for a clean and simple way to preview an Image before I upload it to server, I found different options like Plupload or FancyImageUploader, but I had different problems running it on IE9.
I am not looking to solve those problems, but maybe there is a better and easier way to preview upload Image in IE9..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ajaxupload.js` script. It is present [here](http://zurb.com/playground/javascripts/plugins/ajaxupload.js).

or

You can refer to **[Zurb](http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload)** which has a `JQuery` solution.

Comment: I try to run Zurb Playground on IE9 (no download only running the website) and the preview option didn't work.

Comment: Try with `ajaxupload.js` script.

Comment: Doesn't work, do you have example ? or a link to an example? please

Comment: Refer to this link http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Display-image-preview-before-upload-using-jQuery.aspx